# Ubuntu virtual memory overcommit apparently hitting MySql performance

Tags: server, mysql

I have several installations using Ubuntu Server 10.04 and 12.04 LTS running on Dedicated and VPS with various hosting companies.

I am hitting a problem where, especially on migrating to a new server or after doing apt-get upgrade, MySql runs exceptionally slow. Using various tools to find the problem, including "mysqltuner", "innotop" and "atop". Here is an example from "atop"

```
Atop:
MEM | tot   31.4G | free   26.5G | cache 314.4M | buff   88.0M | slab   59.4M |
SWP | tot    1.0G | free    1.0G |              | vmcom  23.2G | vmlim  16.7G |
DSK |         sdb | busy    100% | read     153 | write    251 | avio   24 ms |
```

(SWP and DSK lines are in red)

MySQLtuner:

```
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 37G (Tables: 11)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 13G (Tables: 79)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 14
```

MySQL config:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size    = 200M
key_buffer_size     = 500M
```

A job that would normally take around 30-60mins is now taking 4 hrs and counting.
I would be grateful if anyone could shed any light on why this might be and suggest ideas to resolve the situation.

Comment: Where is /dev/sdb mounted? I don't see a memory issue here, but 100% disk saturation seems to be telling you something.  Does the performance of MySQL improve after it has been running for a while?

Comment: @rpi-awesomeness: Thanks, I'll bear that in mind. If I move the question to Server Fault SE, I'll change the title.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot: In trying to trace why disk was 100% I was thinking the vm overcommit was part of the problem. MySql does improve after a while, but in 24hrs it's still nowhere near what it was before the update. The server has software raid (mdadm), so isn't /dev/sdb hidden under that?

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: @Fluffy: Sadly, no. We just bought more servers and try to spread the load - giving them a rest if / when they go slow.